# Will web scraping only cause harm to those who have a website?

Tags: web-scraping, server, beautifulsoup, scrapy, scrape

Today I scrape a website using beautifulsoup4 and try to fetch about 16.000 data on that site.
And just few minutes after that, that site got down and can't access about few hours.
So.. my question is:

Will web scraping only cause harm to those who have a website?

Comment: imagine the site owner is you, how you feel it?

Comment: Does it takes same effect with DDoS @ewwink..?

Comment: if you're doing it too fast, yes it almost the same.

Comment: Opinion-based questions don't belong here. But consider, does Google harm websites when it scrapes them? Not if it follows robots.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it is advisable to check out the **`robots.txt`** file of every site before bombarding it with automated requests like you just did. It is not good for the website owner as well as for you. In order to scrape a website, follow these steps before starting to write a web scraper:

1. Check if the website has an API available already to make your task easy. If not, then go to step 2.
2. Check out the **`robots.txt`** file which is present at **`www.anywebsite.com/robots.txt`**. If the owner has listed this page (which in most cases he will), you can see whether **robots** are allowed to access the website or not. If yes, then check out which pages are disallowed and also check if there are any rate-limits for it.
3. If the **`robots.txt`** file is not present, then make sure you are gentle enough not to shoot requests to the website at bullet-speed. It might cause harm to the owner and you might get blocked forever from accessing the site.